# rails 3 removing controller name form url

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm trying to set up some semistatic page in a rails 3 app
I've created a Pages controller with some non restful actions

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end
  def about
  end
  def contact
  end
  def monday
  end
  def saturday
  end
  def sunday
  end

end
```

It's showing at /pages/home etc.
Is there a way to re-route the pages so that they show under /home etc.

I've tried

```
resources :pages, :path => '/' do
  #blah
end
```

but I get an error message telling me that the :action => show is missing.
Is it possible to apply a setting to all non restful actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add collection routes:

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
    get 'home'
    get 'about'
    get 'contact'
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: MAGIC!!! but is it possible to get all of the nested resources without having to write them down manually? or do something like %w{about contact home}.each {|x| get x}  ?

Comment: Yes, your each statement would work fine. I have actually done something similar in cases where I have two resources that have custom routes and route identically. Just keep readability in mind. Also, in this case I'm guessing these are static pages. But in general adding a lot of custom routes like this is considered a smell.

Comment: Yes they all will be pretty much static pages. At least for a start. I'm learning here :) . I did try the each statement but I just got a missing controller error. I'll try again though.