# rails 3 redirect missing url to root

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am trying to set up some semistatic page in a rails 3 app,
I have created a Pages controller with some non restful actions

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end
  def about
  end
  def contact
  end
  def monday
  end
  def saturday
  end
  def sunday
  end

end
```

it's showing the pages well at pages/monday etc... or /monday etc... if i set up the routes as is [rails 3 removing controller name form url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946181/rails-3-removing-controller-name-form-url)

But I was just wondering if it is possible to redirect a missing url to /. As per exampel i have /monday set up, but if one plays with the url and input /tuesday it won't hit a page. can i redirect this kind of actions?

==EDIT==

I've change my code to this:

```
  resources :pages, :path => '/' do
    collection do
      # # match 'tuesday' => redirect('/')
      # # match 'wednesday' => redirect('/')
      # # match 'friday' => redirect('/')
      %w{home monday thursday saturday sunday about contact resources}.each do |url|
        get url
      end
    end
 end
 match 'pages/*page' => :root
```

the url rewriting works fine looping through the array.
I tried the put the wild cardline at the bottom of my root files and at the bottom of the resources :page block. But I get a "controller action show could not be found" message.

```
match 'pages/*page' => :root
```

IS that the correct place to put it to restrain missing url like /tuesday to generate an error page?
is it also possible to limit this redirection only to a few actions and not to all missing pages? ex only to tuesday, wednesday, friday...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcard routes to do this. At the end of your routes.rb just add the line:

```
match '*page' => :root
```

and the missing pages will redirect to root with params[:page] set to the url requested.

If you want to only redirect missing pages in the Pages controller, do this instead

```
match 'pages/*page' => :root
```

You can read more about routing [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Wildcard routes are explained near the end of the article.

Hope this helped!

Comment: tried this but didn't put it at the end. thought it would be overwritten by the other declarations.

Answer (score 2):

got it working

I changed the wildcard line to

```
match '*page' => redirect('/')
```

instead of => :root, and left it within the resources :pages block.

Comment: this said, ist possible to limit the redirect to just a few url, aka /tuesday, /friday ...